# How to Import excel file by selecting id from another table for excel column

Tags: php, import

I need to import csv into database using php .It is working .But I need to find id from another table for excel column and import it into database .
My Import code

```
if ($_FILES["downtime"]["size"] > 0) {
     //  echo("<script>location.href = 'adhocadd.php';</script>");
     $file = fopen($fileName, "r");
    // fgetcsv($handle);
       fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",");
      while (($row = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                
                  $station_id=$row[0];
                  // $linename=$row[1];
                   $line=$row[1];
                   // $line=$lineid;
                  //  $getexcellinesmodel=getexcellines($mysql_connectionLinkLocal,$line);
                     //$lineid=array();
                   
                    $starttime=$row[2];
                    $endtime=$row[3];
                    $duration=$row[4];
                    $category=$row[5];
                    $reason=$row[6];
                    $detail=$row[7];
                    $comment=$row[8];
                    $action=$row[9];
                    $problempartnumber=$row[10];
                    $expectedpartnumber=$row[11];
                    $cartnumber=$row[12];
                     $reporter=$row[13];
                     $entrytype=$row[14];
                     $shift=$row[15];
                     $options=$row[16];
                     $updated_at=$row[17];
                       
                   
                     $importdowntime=importdowntime($mysql_connectionLinkLocal,$station_id,$line,$duration,$category,$reason,$detail,$comment,$action,$problempartnumber,$expectedpartnumber,$cartnumber,$reporter,$entrytype,$shift,$options,$updated_at,$starttime,$endtime);        
     
                
      } 
      $success="downtime imported successfully "; 
     echo("<script>location.href = 'upload.php?success=$success';</script>");
           

   }
```

It is importing data into downtime table.
$row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVpAn.png) contains linename .I need to find id of that linename from line table and import into the downtime table . [image]

Comment: You need to provide more info for an answer, e.g. data sample of your _line_ table, and where exactly you expect it to be imported.

Comment: Line table contains id ,linename , shift fields .I need to import CSV into downtime table .It has line id .I want  to import excel that has only linename.